# can't delete record from mongodb dbase using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js

Following "Developing Backbone js" http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#talking-to-the-server (search "parse function")

on click "Delete": the book is not deleted from the server (dbase) even with this "parse" function operating OK... the DELETE http command is given, with the correct ID for the book... but this doesn't delete it from the dbase...

generated URL command looks like this:

```
DELETE http://localhost:4711/api/books/5417ff846b205d9c05000001
```

... this is triggering the following function in server.js

```
app.delete( '/api/books/:id', function( request, response ) {
   console.log( 'Deleting book with id: ' + request.params.id );
   ...
```

... but the DELETE command never "returns" (in FF Console you just get the spinner, which doesn't go away)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server.js, setup your server as follows:

```
// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require("express"),   // Web framework
    path = require("path"),         // Utilities for dealing with file paths
    mongoose = require('mongoose'); // MongoDB integration

//Create server
var app = express.createServer();

// Configure server
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());     // parses request body and populates req.body
    app.use(express.methodOverride()); // checks req.body for HTTP method overrides
    app.use(app.router); // perform route lookup based on url and HTTP method
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public"))); // Where to serve static content
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions:true, showStack:true })); // Show all errors in development
});

//Start server
app.listen(4711, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});

//  Connect to database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/library_database');


//Schemas
var Book = new  mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    author:String,
    releaseDate: Date
});

//Models
var BookModel = mongoose.model('Book', Book);
```

Try creating the delete route as follows:

```
app.delete('/api/books/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log('Deleting book with id: ' + req.params.id);
    return BookModel.findById(req.params.id, function(err, book){
        return book.remove(function(err){
            if(!err){
                console.log('Book removed');
                return res.send('');
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And test it via AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/api/books/5417ff846b205d9c05000001',
  type: 'DELETE',
  success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log("Post resposne:");
    console.dir(data);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.dir(jqXHR);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks... yes in fact I tried that ("Command Editor" in Firefox)... same thing happens, i.e. the DELETE never returns (sorry was a bit confused about what was happening: in fact "Deleting book..." *is* printed (in the node.js terminal window).  Maybe I have got a "server problem" too...

Comment: Did you include the line `app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions:true, showStack:true }));` in your server.js to show server errors stack trace?

Comment: thanks!  I changed from var app = express(); to var app = express.createServer();... and it worked.  However I also got a message saying this "createServer" way of doing things is "deprecated"... maybe, but it works.

Comment: Now I'm really confused... I went back to var app=express() with your errorHandler line in place, restarted the server, and tried deleting again... worked perfectly! So the circumstances under which var app = express() does *not* work need investigating I suppose.

Comment: Indeed quite baffling, I supposed you are using Express < 3.x version hence the `createServer` method which is indeed deprecated in > 3.x. Expressjs wraps and extends `http` in Node thus `express()` builds on top of `http.createServer()`